# Juniper Networks SRX240 as a office router?

Tags: networking, router, juniper

We're a small (7 person) fast growing startup who just got our new office and we're having a 100 Mbps line installed from Cogent. I'm not familiar with Juniper devices, however the equivalent Cisco appears to be rather expensive.

Features we'd like:

1. Offsite VPN access (PPTP or L2TP IPsec) - something Mac compatible
2. IPv6 support
3. NAT - ideally supporting multiple outside addresses mapped to VLANs
4. DHCP
5. DNS forwarding would be nice
6. QoS to keep our SIP phones happy (managed through RingCentral)
7. VLANs for guest/internal

The device is going to be connected to a set of SIP phones as well as two Ruckus 7962s for wireless access. Eventually I'd like to connect it to a Juniper ESX switch as we grow.

Would a Juniper SRX240 handle this ok?

Answer (score 3):

The SRX240 will meet these requirements, and is probably overkill for 7 users. An SRX 100,210 or 220 will get the job done most likely.

However, I've found the "dynamic VPN" used for client connections to be a little less than easy to configure and I'm unsure if they have a Mac client. I gave up on it in the past and just setup a small linux box on the inside for PPTP connections.

Comment: We're adding 2-3 people per month to our team, so I hoping this could handle an office of ~25-30 in about a year. Good to know about Dynamic VPN.

Comment: I've used an SRX100 to handle over 100 users before.

Answer (score 0):

Our office of about 30 people uses a SRX100 with no problems at all. Our BW in not as high as yours, but I agree that the 240 is most likely overkill.  For roadwariors we use openvpn server, but the SRX is good for site2site vpn.

Comment: I haven't looked in a while, but I think their "dynamic vpn" for client connections is almost there.